# Any place to download ATMOP's DTM-2012 / DTM-2013 models?

Tags: atmospheric-drag

Once there were an old "Drag Temperature Models" DTM2012 and DTM2013 at http://www.atmop.eu
According to web archive in 2020 they were still available for downloading after registration:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200809075513/http://www.atmop.eu/index.php/downloads

It seems now ATMOP project is closed. The site is dead.
I'm interested in a DTM2012/2013 data files and perhaps a linux binary.
Is there any way to get this data?

Answer (score 2):

It seems at least DTM2012 data can be found in c++/data sources coming with *Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications* by David Vallado: https://celestrak.org/software/vallado-sw.php

Some input files are missing: smoothratio_500to350km, smoothratio_kpmin4-to-max3, smoothrelvar_350km_kpmax3, but I found their DTM2013 versions here: https://github.com/juppiega/goce/tree/master/data
I hope they are the same.